# access file in datanode from namenode hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I have configured the **namenode** in **hadoopmaster** and data node in **hadoopslave**.When **start-dfs.sh** in hadoopmaster the namenode in hadoopmaster and datanode in hadoopslave getting started.when i try to execute the command **hdfs dfs -ls /** in hadoopmaster i can't view the files that i had put in hadoopslave.
Note:I put a file in hadoopslave using **hdfs dfs -put /sample.txt /** 
Correct me if I'am wrong!

Comment: @Prabhu hdfs -put src file path dst file path(hdfs) has to be given. Also check on the hadoop cluster configurations once again.

Comment: In your command, you are specifying source file as **/sample.txt**. Means that file present in **root** folder ??

Comment: @Pendlimarri's no its not in root it's in my desktop put when i give that path also it's not working

Comment: @madhu when I try that it's showing unknown host exception

Comment: Please add some error logs to the question .